# Is PL/SQL the language to learn if you have Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, plsql

is PL/SQL the language of Oracle 11g?  Is there some other langauge that Oracle uses?  I don't mean front end applications that use other languages, just if I am in the database directly.  I ask because I know SQL Server will let you use various .NET languages and didn't know if Oracle had something other than pl/sql.

Thanks.

EDIT:  I just want to make sure pl/sql is not dead or anything.  I'd hate to learn it and build procedure in the database with it and someone say...well you should have used....x.

Comment: Pl/sql is most cases the most intelligent solution to implement data manipulation programs. Learn it and you realize how fast and efficent it is. And pl/sql database programs can be called almost from any framework, so it's like interface to other applications also. So I don't think that someone is ever saying that you should have used something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the most part, I think the answer is "Yes". I think that it's also possible to load Java and C modules so they can call/be called by PL/SQL code in the database, but I myself have never seen this done. I'm not sure where to look for information on this, but now you have other leads to research ;)

Example of a Java stored procedure: http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3337411/Oracle-and-Java-Stored-Procedures.htm

..and don't worry about PL/SQL being dead or dying. I think it's still the way most stored procedures and in-database code is written for Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle:

> PL/SQL is an imperative 3GL that was
>   designed specifically for the seamless
>   processing of SQL commands. It
>   provides specific syntax for this
>   purpose and supports exactly the same
>   datatypes as SQL. Server-side PL/SQL
>   is stored and compiled in Oracle
>   Database and runs within the Oracle
>   executable. It automatically inherits
>   the robustness, security, and
>   portability of Oracle Database.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Taking the information of the following link:
[`1 Introduction to Oracle Database Extensions for .NET`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14306/intro.htm)

Bear with me that I have never ever used CLR extensions, not even with SQL Server, so I can't be of any further assistance. I only think the information provided by this above link is related and might provide useful tips.

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL is very good for doing a lot of DML in a stored procedure.  If you're using forms and reports then it also the language of choice.  The disadvantage is it's not portable and doesn't interface that well with the tons of libraries available for other environments.  I do most my heavy DB work in PL/SQL but all the web applications and things that have to integrate other systems using J2EE and JDBC.