# Why PL/SQL going down

Tags: plsql

I was going through [TIOBE](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) list of programming languages and I noticed that PL/SQL is going down. Its not that i am big fan of Pl/SQL, I hardly know it but my question is if Pl/Sql is going down then there must be some alternate which is helping developers to achieve the same tasks which were supposed to be done by Pl/SQL i.e. stored procedures, packages etc? What are those things?

Answer (score 1):

I think your reading into it the wrong way. PL/SQL is an extension of Oracle's database. If PL/SQL is in decline then most likely Oracle is losing market share.

Comment: thats what i am thinking. But last answer confused me a lot. Look at the TIOBE index and you will notice that Pl/Sql is declining.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, it's possible to write Oracle stored procedures in Java. As it happens, for non-trivial operations, I prefer doing that to using PL/SQL. But I doubt that there are very many like me, so I think that it's unlikely to account for the decline.

See also the answers to this question: [Is PL/SQL the language to learn if you have Oracle 11g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227137/is-pl-sql-the-language-to-learn-if-you-have-oracle-11g)

Answer (score 0):

Also Oracle Forms applications are nowadays more heading to JDeveloper, so interface programming will be made more with Java than with PL/SQL. Like Oracle's e-busines suite...

Answer (score -1):

That would be Transact-SQL.

Comment: isn't it specific to microsoft? or i am missing lots of things here .. S:?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft is gaining market share. Therefore Oracle is losing it. Therefore PL/SQL is going down.