# Performance Comparison of Stored Procedure written in Pl/SQL vs. Java

Tags: java, performance, stored-procedures, plsql, java-stored-procedures

After going through the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288624/why-pl-sql-going-down/4298633#4298633) I have one more question now.

Lets assume, there is an **enterprise** level application with million of user base and with millions of transaction each day. Performance vise, which would be better.

1. [Java Stored Procedure](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/10920_3337411_2/Oracle-and-Java-Stored-Procedures.htm)
2. Or Oracle Stored Procedures (Pl/SQL)

*P.S: When i say **enterprise** application development, I meant it from developers point of view where we have different layers of abstraction. Testing frameworks. Automated Testing deployed on multiple blades and extensive debugging etc*

Comment: Newer versions of Oracle can compile PL/SQL to native code.  Seems like mixing in Java just adds another level of complexity and abstraction.  PL/SQL is a pretty powerful language by itself

Comment: What about unit testing those PL/SQL procedures? lets say we have 1000 of procedures?

Comment: If any of the Java code involves trips back & forth to perform an operation -- PLSQL will be faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect performance issues will come down to what kind of database operations you're doing. However a very important issue for me when dealing with databases is testability. Many times I've been in projects with are too centric around the database - where we end up with tons of business logic that I can't unit test, verify or perhaps even change.

I'm always for the pragmatic choice - everything in it's right place. And for some stuff you really should keep it in the database. But this is an issue worth thinking about.

Comment: I believe writing Stored Procedures in Java would give the ability to run JUnit tests. But again, Would running a java based stored procedure compared to other add an extra overhead to the server? 

Lets for clarity, keep the application a generic applciation which has balanced business logic on either side (database, java code). What would be the suggestiosn then?

Comment: I'm sure it would add overhead. Doesn't a VM always? But then, computers are fast, hardware cheap and the benefits of having the VM generally outweighs the negatives. So the question comes down to - what is going to be done? Counting every cpu cycle, squeezing every last bit of throughput possible - most definitely not java. But I haven't been around many such systems.

Comment: I vote for unit tested business logic and java. But I'm biased :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine there will be much difference between the two for most applications, unless your stored procedures are highly compute-heavy (and note that I mean computation within the procedure itself, not the computation involved in executing individual SQL statements).

Now, as for the difference between stored procedures generally and ordinary application code, that's another story.